# How to configure mule https-connector to consume webservice?

Tags: java, web-services, https, mule, client-certificates

Okay, my last post did not really get any audience, do I'll try to clarify myself a bit. :)

Could someone give me an example how I should configure my https-connector in order to consume webservice that is secured by client-authentication (i.e. I need to authenticate to the server with sertificate)?

This is my current configuration:

```
<https:connector name="WSConnector" keepAlive="true" proxyHostname="${proxyHostname}"
    proxyPort="${proxyPort}">
  <https:tls-client path="${keystore.location}" storePassword="${keystore.password}" />

  <https:tls-key-store path="${keystore.location}"
    keyPassword="${keystore.password}"
    storePassword="${keystore.password}"
    keyAlias="${keystore.keyAlias}" />

  <https:tls-server path="${truststore.location}" storePassword="${truststore.password}" />
</https:connector>
```

In this configuration I have a Thawte certificate and it's private key in "keystore" and server's CA certificate in my "truststore". Is this how this should be done?

Comment: What was your solution please? As I have the same question

Comment: If I recall correctly, then this configuration was not the problem. My problem was that the keychain was not correctly created to the keystore and the connection failed everytime because of that.